# Cordova catching UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT buttons

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, cordova

I am writing a cordova app for an android 4.4.2 device. This device has a remote-control, where I need to catch the <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, and <kbd>Right</kbd>-keys.

Unfortunately cordova only supports catching events for vol-up, vol-down, menu, search and back-keys ([See documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html))

So I tried to write my own plugin, but unfortunately I am stuck and do not know how to proceed.

**Java-Part (simplified):**

```
public OwnPlugin() {}

  public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);
  }

  public boolean execute(final String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if (action.equals("overrideUpButton")) {
      this.overrideUpButton(args.getBoolean(0));
    }
    return true;
  }

  public void overrideUpButton(boolean override) {
    webView.setButtonPlumbedToJs(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, override);
  }
}
```

**JS-Part (simplified):**

```
cordova.define("com. ... ", function(require, exports, module) {
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

function OwnPlugin() {
}

OwnPlugin.prototype.overrideUpButton = function(override, onsucess, onfail){
 exec(onsucess, onfail, "OwnPlugin", "overrideUpButton" ,[ override ]);
};


 var ownPlugin = new OwnPlugin();
 module.exports = ownPlugin;
});
```

This gives me an exception, when trying to override the button with `OwnPlugin.overrideUpButton(true);`:

```
E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
E/PluginManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported keycode: 19
E/PluginManager:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.setButtonPlumbedToJs(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:366)
```

Ok... this approach will not work, since my needed button codes are not supported in `CordovaWebViewImpl.java`

So what can I do now? How can I catch those Key-Codes, so I can prevent the default action, and work with them in JavaScript?

- KEYPAD_DPAD_UP
- KEYPAD_DPAD_DOWN
- KEYPAD_DPAD_LEFT
- KEYPAD_DPAD_RIGHT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to catch those keys

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSomething, false);
 
function moveSomething(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            // left key pressed
            break;
        case 38:
            // up key pressed
            break;
        case 39:
            // right key pressed
            break;
        case 40:
            // down key pressed
            break;  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Seems my thoughts were way to complicated... Thanks!